# How can I vent a bath fan with no access to exterior?

Tags: exhaust-fan

We are redoing our bathroom and just discovered when we were replacing the fan that is wasn't vented out anywhere. How can we vent now? It's between floors with no windows and a brick wall. The only option we can see would be downdraft. Any solutions>?

Comment: What is on the other side of the brick wall?

Comment: It is possible to put a vent  pipe through a brick wall.

Answer (score 2):

You need to vent the moisture outside. If you have access to the outer wall cut a hole into the sheathing it can be bigger than the duct. Then, using a masonry bit, drill a single hole through the brick where the center of the duct will be for reference. I suggest not using a hammer drill so as not to bust or crack the brick causing unwanted problems.

Now go outside using the center hole for reference mark on the brick mark the opening you will need.  Now drill a series of holes alone the mark fairly close together taking your time and be careful--it's better that the opening is smaller than needed because you can always remove more material.

It's important that you not hurry and drill from the brick facade.  This is because sometimes when drilling thru the back of the brick can break off uneven. Run the duct thru the hole install and seal the vent cover.

Comment: Core drills for masonry can be rented at most tool rental shops. They'll typically do a 4' bore without special braces.

Answer (score 0):

Exhaust fans that filter the air and don't need a vent are available from Amazon and the big-box home improvement stores.  You can search for "duct-free exhaust fans".

I've never used or installed one of these, so I don't know how well they work.

Comment: Those would not work for moisture. So they are only suitable for bathrooms without a tub or shower.